# How to set the page layout dimensions in ConTeXt?

Tags: margins, context, context-mkiv

Using the instructions found in the [page design](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-pagedesign.pdf) chapter of the ConTeXt user manual, I have attempted to set my own page dimensions, but have not been able to understand the instructions. For e.g., there are options for `leftmargin`, `leftedge`, `leftmargindistance`, `leftedgedistance`, but I do not understand how these translate to the page. To further complicate matters, when I compiled any documents, with `showframe`, `\showstruts`, and `\showgrid` options on, lots of red lines appeared in my document, suggesting there were many complex dimensions to set, as illustrated here:

```
 _____________________ _____________________
|  _   _________   _  |  _   _________   _  |                       
| |_| |         | |_| | |_| |         | |_| |
| |_| |         | |_| | |_| |         | |_| |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |                     
| | | |         | | | | | | |         | | | |
| |_| |_________| |_| | |_| |_________| |_| |
| |_| |_________| |_| | |_| |_________| |_| |
| |_| |_________| |_| | |_| |_________| |_| |
|_____________________|_____________________|
       (verso)                 (recto)
```

Generally, my page dimension needs are quite basic. Here is an illustration:

```
 _____________________ _____________________
|       ^             |             ^       |
|       a             |             a       |
|      _v_____        |        _____v_      |
|     |   ^   |       |       |       |     |
|     |   |   |       |       |       |     |
|<-b->|   c   |<--d-->|<--d-->|<--e-->|<-b->|
|     |   |   |       |       |       |     |
|     |___v___|       |       |_______|     |
|       ^ ^           |           ^ ^       |
|       | f           |           f |       |
|       | v           |           v |       |
|       g #           |           # g       |
|       |             |             |       |
|       |             |             |       |
|_______v_____________|_____________v_______|
       (verso)                 (recto)
```

a - length of top margin
b - width of outer margin
c - height of text area
d - width of gutter
e - width of text area
f - length of space between text area and page number
g - length of bottom margin

- The dimensions of the verso pages and recto pages are identical, but mirrored at the gutter.
- Any footnote text should appear within the text area.
- Margin notes are not used.
- The dimensions of `c` and `e` need not be set, these can fill the available dimensions left on the page.

How can I set the page layout dimensions in my document in ConTeXt?

Comment: Have a look at the [ConTeXt wiki - Layout](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [typesetting area in ConTeXt comprises twenty five areas](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Page_Layout#Typesetting_areas) (`cutspace` is missing in the figure):

[image: context typesetting areas]

You only need to [set up](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuplayout) text area and footer
(for the page number):

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided, location=footer]

\setuplayout
  [header=0pt,
   margin=0pt,
   footerdistance=1cm,
   topspace=1cm,
   backspace=1cm,
   cutspace=8cm,
   width=fit,
   % margin bottom of text to paper
   height=\dimexpr
    \paperheight-\topspace+\footerheight+\footerdistance-5cm\relax]

\starttext
  \showlayout
  \null
\stoptext
```

`\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]` switches to the
mirrored layout on even pages.
When the top area and the header is set to zero,
`topspace` states the distance from the top of the paper to the text area
and `backspace` the distance from the left to the text.
`cutspace` is the distance from the right of the text to the paper.
For these to apply correctly, `width=fit` needs to be set.

The distance from the bottom of the text to the paper cannot be set
directly but can be computed. The `5cm` in the `height=` line states
the distance from the bottom of the text to the bottom of the paper.

Comment: Beware that `topheight`/`bottomheight` are defined by setting `top`/`bottom` respectively (i.e. write `top=3cm`, NOT `topheight=3cm`), and that `topdistance`/`bottomdistance` will remain 0, whatever you set it to, if `topheight`/`bottomheight` are 0.

Answer (score 1):

One part of Marco's answer seems to me misleading in that `top`, `bottom`, `footer`, `header`, it appears, are the real effective way to change these parameters.

```
\setuplayout [
   backspace=25mm,
   margin=20mm,
   margindistance=0mm,
   width=160mm,
   topspace=20mm,
   height=260mm,
   header=10mm,
   footer=15mm,
   bottomdistance=0mm,
   bottom=10mm
]
```

Other lines he points out seem to work.
If I am wrong do tell me.